# Detecting user-initiated page unload vs browser crashing

Tags: javascript, mobile

I have some memory-intensive WebGL code which runs in both desktop and mobile devices. The user is able to add/remove WebGL modules thereby changing the memory requirements for the page. On low-power devices its possible for the user to get themselves into a bad state. They try to load the page, but the page runs out of memory due to too many modules loading. The page crashes. I am working on providing the user with a means of recovering from this scenario.

Some high-level pseudocode for my recovery solution looks like:

- During init, write a flag to sessionStorage for each module. The flag indicates the given module has not loaded yet.
- If a module already has a flag in storage - don't try to load it.
- For every other module - attempt to load.
- As each module loads, clear its flag.

Overall, this code has the effect of preventing the browser from attempting to load all modules every time.

**However**, I also clear a module's load flag if the user refreshes the page. A manual page refresh is not a browser crash -- and thus all modules should continue to try and load:

```
window.addEventListener('unload', function() { /* clear flags here */ });
```

This all seems to work fine in desktop environments, but in testing mobile devices I've found that often times the browser refreshes the page automatically instead of crashing. In Safari, I see an error message:

> "A problem occurred with this webpage so it was reloaded."

---

**Is it possible to detect a manual page refresh vs a 'browser error recovery' refresh?**

To the best of my knowledge the answer is, 'No.' as I only have a window unload event to work with in both scenarios.